# Password Protection a ZIP file using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, password-protection

I have a copy data activity which will compress multiple files and move it to a .zip file. Is it possible to password protect the .zip file in Azure Data Factory?

Any leads would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Arjun Rathinam

Comment: Hi @Arjun Rathinam, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for now, Data Factory doesn't support read and generate password protected file.

We can't do it and there isn't any good workarounds for it. Most closed way is that you create the Azure Function or notebook to do it, then run it in Data Factory.

You can post a new feedback here:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory. The product team may see it and think about add these feature.

Comment: thanks for the update. Azure Function seems to be a good idea.

Comment: @ArjunRathinam yes, but you need build the code by yourself. Data Factory can't achieve it directly with exist actives. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.